# I need help writing a function in EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula, data-analysis

I have data where I have the country code, and the year. each country has a population according to that year.

however, I want to add a column with the GDP for each country for each year.

I didn't succeed to create a function in excel that matched the data from one sheet to another.

In the first sheet column, A represents the country code, and then from B1 to AH1, it's the years.

I want to match the GDP values by the country code and a specific year to the GDP column.

First sheet, need to fill GDP values according to year and country code
[image]

Match by year and country code

[image]

I tried many functions but it didn't work well. I'm looking for a function that will match the values to the GDP according to the Country code and Year, from both sheets.

Comment: Use INDEX with a MATCH to return the row and another MATCH to return the correct column.

Comment: I would like to see come CSV data from each table, first 100 rows from table_1 that has the population and the blank column,  and first 10 rows from table_2 that has the GDP.  That way we can test and demonstrate our results.

Comment: What about `=INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$AB$46,MATCH(Sheet1!$A2,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$46,0),MATCH(Sheet1!$B2,Sheet2!$A$1:$AB$1,0))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### `INDEX` With `XMATCH` Row and Column

- In cell `C2` you could use the following (array/spilling) formula:

```
=IFNA(INDEX(Sheet2!B2:D6,XMATCH(A2:A21,Sheet2!A2:A6),XMATCH(B2:B21,Sheet2!B1:D1)),"")
```

[image]

- Alternatively, you could use the following `LAMBDA` formula...

  ```
  =LAMBDA(RowValues,ColValues,SourceData,
      IFNA(INDEX(DROP(SourceData,1,1),
          XMATCH(RowValues,DROP(TAKE(SourceData,,1),1)),
          XMATCH(ColValues,DROP(TAKE(SourceData,1),,1))),"")))
  ```

  to create a defined name (your own function) e.g. `LookupRC` and utilize it with the simple:

  ```
  =LookupRC(A2:A21,B2:B21,Sheet2!A1:D6)
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much!! you saved me so much time. Much appreciated.n